# How to execute a code after a copyTpl is completed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, io

I'm sort of a beginner with Node.js and I was trying to execute something **after** the following code was completed:

```
fs.copyTpl(
  this.templatePath('.gitignore'),
  this.destinationPath('.gitignore'),
  {
    projectName: this.props.projectName
  }
);
```

I need either to change this function to call a synchronous implementation (but libraries like fs-extra for example do not provide this copyTpl function or to use a callback. But I don't really know how to do it, I try using then() but my syntax is not working.

Thanks for the help